# Curb protectors on back of rolling luggage

Tags: luggage

I bought new luggage with wheels recently and realized that the two rubberized skids/glides/protectors that were attached vertically on my old luggage are not on my new luggage. I am trying to find the parts so that I can attach them to my new luggage and protect the back of the cases when dragging them up a curb. Does anyone know what these are called? They are generally 12 to 24 inches in height, see eg the photo below.

[image]

Comment: Maybe check the description of luggage that has them to find how they name them?

Comment: I have, but they don't mention that part.